# Append Data in Batch

Tags: batch-file, scripting

this is part of a logon script. The script runs every time the user logs into their computer. What the script needs to do is log to the same file every time it is run, but I do not want it to overwrite data. I want it to add to the line below. I am having trouble figuring it out, this is all I have so far:

```
if not exist "C:\Windows\LogonScript" mkdir C:\Windows\LogonScript"
(echo Username: %USERNAME%
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Domain"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Name" 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Manufacturer"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Model"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System type"
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Total Physical Memory" 
ipconfig | findstr IPv4
echo Hard Drive Information:
wmic LOGICALDISK where drivetype=3 get caption,size,FreeSpace) > C:\Windows\LogonScript\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt

xcopy /s C:\Windows\LogonScript\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt \\ess\Home\cgoodwin\Scripts

exit
```

Comment: Change `) > C:\Windows\LogonScript\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt` to `)>>"C:\Windows\LogonScript\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will append using the answer I gave in my comment. Additionally it should be considerably faster, *(by just running a single instance of the really slow systeminfo command)*:

```bat
If Not Exist "C:\Windows\LogonScript\" MD "C:\Windows\LogonScript"
(Echo UserName:                  %UserName%
SystemInfo|FindStr/IL /C:"Host Name:" /C:"Domain:" /C:"OS Name:"^
 /C:"System Manufacturer:" /C:"System Model:" /C:"System Type:"^
 /C:"Total Physical Memory:"
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%A In ('IPConfig^|Find "IPv4"'
) Do Echo=IP Address:               %%A
Echo(
Echo Logical Disk Information:
WMIC LogicalDisk Where DriveType=3 Get Caption, Size, FreeSpace|More
)>>"C:\Windows\LogonScript\%ComputerName%.txt"
```